# I keep having issues with scaling my texture in Image Editor. At first I have the cuts or sections and then I cannot access them

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Sorry this is probably a dumb question. I keep having this issue where I no longer have the ability to scale my textures. At first I can then the boxes or shapes that are over the texture seem to no longer be there. I am very new to blender so I am sure this is a simple fix. I will attach an image as well.

Thanks[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, you appear to not actually be in the UV editor window. Open the UV editing subpanel from the top bar to the right of your file button.

Comment: That worked I am a total idiot. So you can still view it I guess, but not actually be in the window to adjust it then? I was clicking the dropdown just under the blender logo button next to file. I guess that is just to view but does not actually switch you over. Wow thanks so much. I kept having this problem all the time and could not figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: No problem, dumb mistakes are common especially when starting out. Don't beat yourself up over it.